# add days to month not exceeding last day of the month php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have date in this form -  - `20160428000000` (28th April 2016) i.e yyyymmdd...

I need that if some days(eg. 3) are added to this date - it should add them but not exceed the month(04) - expected output - `20160430000000` - 30th April

Similarly, `20160226000000` + 5days should return `20160229000000` i.e leap year Feb. That means, it should not jump to another month.

Any hints/Ideas ?

Comment: get the interval between your date and last date ot the month. If this interval is less than given interval for adding, just return last day of the month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative would be to use `DateTime` classes to check it out:

First of course create your object thru the input. Then, set the ending day of the month object.

After that, make the addition then check if it exceeds the ending day. If yes, set it to the end, if not, then get the result of the addition:

```
$day = 5; // days to be added
$date = '20160226000000'; // input date
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', $date); // create the input date
$end = clone $dt; // clone / copy the input
$end->modify('last day of this month'); // and set it to last day
$dt->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString("+{$day} days")); // add x days
// make comparision
$final_date = ($dt > $end) ? $end->format('YmdHis') : $dt->format('YmdHis');
echo $final_date;
```

Comment: nice and elegant! +1

Comment: I was about to suggest something similar using `DateTimeImmutable`, but it's basically the same logic. +1 :)

Comment: Accepted, because it returns the date in the same form which I've mentioned. Thanks

Comment: @jitendrapurohit sure glad this hlped

Answer (score 1):

For this you can try like this:

```
$given_date = 20160428000000;
$no_of_day = 3;

if(date('m',strtotime($given_date)) < date('m',strtotime($given_date ." +".$no_of_day."days"))){
    echo "Exceeded to next month <br/>";
    echo "Last date of month should be: ".date("t M Y", strtotime($given_date));
}
else {
    echo "Next date will be after ".$no_of_day." day(s)<br/>";
    echo date('d M Y',strtotime($given_date ." +".$no_of_day."days"));
}
```

If month will jump to next month then it will show the current month last date.
other wise it will show date after number of days extended.

Comment: Thanks, but will this give me the last date - 30 april ?

Comment: @jitendrapurohit! Yes it will, try it.

Answer (score 0):

If the added date exceeds last day, will select the last day as the new date.

```
<?php
$date_orig  = 20160226000000;
$add_day    = 5; # No. of days to add

$added_date      = strtotime($date_orig. ' + '.$add_day.' days'); // Add $add_day to $date_orig 
$last_date       = strtotime(date("YmtHis", strtotime($date_orig))); // Last day of $date_orig 
$new_date        = ($added_date > $last_date) ? $last_date : $added_date; // check the added date exceeds the last date
$new_date_format = date("YmdHis", $new_date); // Format Date

echo $new_date_format;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $month_end = date('t-m-Y'); // Gets the last day of the month; e.g 31-07-2019
    echo $month_end;
?>
```